# How to use a variable within a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to find an image with a 'src' that matches a variable. I have used 'alert' to make sure the variable 'currentThumbnail' is correct, so I think the problem is down to syntax. This is what I have at the moment:

```
var currentImage = $('.imageMain').attr('src');
var currentThumbnail = currentImage.substring(6);
var nextT = $('.thumbnails a img[src=currentThumbnail]');
```

The problem is with 'img[src=currentThumbnail]'. What do I need to change to make this valid?

I'd be happy to add any more information if it's unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var nextT = $('.thumbnails a img[src=currentThumbnail]');
```

should be

```
var nextT = $('.thumbnails a img[src="'+ currentThumbnail +'"]');
```

You need String concatenation, because you're using variable `currentThumbnail` within a string.

#### An important commment from @ThiefMaster

> The attribute values in selectors should be quoted. The docs says it's
> a requirement and I think the only reason why it's not enforced is
> backwards compatibility

Comment: My previous comment stated that attribute values must be quoted. Actually, re-checking the docs showed me that they changed this again - it only has to follow the W3C CSS attribute selector requirements, i.e. values that are not simple (i.e. contain whitespace or other non-alnum characters) need to be quoted, others may or may not be quoted. However, since the value is taken from a variable quoting is certainly good.

Comment: This seems to work but is it missing double quotes? It outputs the error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [src=first.gif]" in Chrome.